# Text binding lookup value from list

Tags: knockout.js

I have a view model (billing) which i am referencing from a second view model (summary).

Specifically, I have a combo box which shows the country. The binding works, but on the summary view model view, it gets the code of the country (i.e. "AO"), whereas I want to display the name ("Angola").

I could create a ko.computed property on the billing vm to get the country name, but is there any other way to do this than create this extra function?

**Billing view model**

```
function Billing() {
    var self = this;

    var countries = [
      { name: 'Afghanistan', code: 'AF' },
      { name: 'Åland Islands', code: 'AX' },
      { name: 'Albania', code: 'AL' },
      { name: 'Algeria', code: 'DZ' },
      { name: 'American Samoa', code: 'AS' },
      { name: 'Andorra', code: 'AD' },
      { name: 'Angola', code: 'AO' }
      ];

    self.country = ko.observable('AO');
    };
```

**Billing view**

```
<select id="country" class="col-md-4 form-control" data-bind="options: countriesList, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'code', value: country, attr: { placeholder: 'Country' }"></select>
```

**Summary view model**

```
function (ko) {
    function Summary(configurationVm, billingVm) {
        var self = this;        
        self.configurationVm = ko.observable(configurationVm);
        self.billingVm = ko.observable(billingVm);
        console.log("two types: %o, %o", self.configurationVm, self.billingVm);
     };

    return (Summary);
});
```

**Summary view (snipped to relevant country section)**

```
<!-- ko with: billingVm -->
<span data-bind="text: country"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: You could remove the `optionsValue: 'code'` in this case `Billing`'s `country` will hold the whole country object `{ name: 'Angola', code: 'AO' }` so there is no need for the computed. However in this case you need to set your country with: `self.country = ko.observable(ko.utils.arrayFirst(countries, function(c) { return c.code == 'AO'}));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove optionsValue: 'code'. That way the value will be the country itself and not just the code. You can then use country.name to get the name and country.code to get the code:

```
<select id="country" class="col-md-4 form-control" data-bind="options: countriesList, optionsText: 'name', value: country, attr: { placeholder: 'Country' }"></select>
<!-- ko with: country -->
<span data-bind="text: name"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wk7dr/13/